# Олимпиадная задача с повышенной сложностью

Tags: c++

Салют всем чайникам и гуру, девелоперам и фрилансерам, прогерам и кодерам! Но речь не о классификации и иерархии нашего брата. Речь о олимпиадной задачи, которую я уже неделю не могу решить. Я точно знаю: решение что-то простое и гениальное - но вот под каким камнем оно спряталось? Так что, суровые хэшкод-юзеры, прошу у вас помощь в решение этой задачи!

Задача:
Язык программирования: С++.
В программе должна быть 1 единственная функция вывода информации, которая может только писать, т.е. не может удалять текст, а только вставлять новый. При этом она работает следующий образом

### Исполняемый код:

```
func( "1" );
```

---

### Вывод:

```
(1)
[1]
```

---

### Исполняемый код:

```
func( "1" );
func( "2" );
```

---

### Вывод

```
(1)
(2)
[2]
[1]
```

---

### Испоняемый код:

```
func( "1" );
func( "2" );
func( "qwer" );
```

---

### Вывод

```
(1)
(2)
(qwer)
[qwer]
[2]
[1]
```

---

Я уверен, что задача решается легко, но у меня нет других вариантов, кроме как все же буферизовать хвост, изменять его, и заменять старый хвост на новый. Но тогда приходится использовать удаление символов.

P.S. задача не совсем олимпиадная, эта задачка была давно в какой-то мощной статье по альтернативному программирование где рассматривалось несколько примеров, но вот код реализации такой задачи не помню. И статью ту тоже не могу найти. У самого без удаление символов написать не получается.

Comment: Я может чего не так понял, но разве надо не просто напечатать аргументы, а потом напечатать их в обратном порядке с другими скобками?

Comment: Нет. Тут не как обычно. Не просто аргументы пишешь. Тут работа на прямую с кодом. Мы не вводим аргументы. Мы вызываем поочередно функции с аргумента, а после выполнения видим вот такой вот результат. Выше я укзал, что если исполняемый код в main() func( "1" ); - то результат такой-то, а если добавить дальше func( "2" ); то результат изменится на такой.

Comment: Оу, точно. Спасибо =) Можно же это в деструкторе прописать.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Испоняемый код:

func( "1" ); func( "2" ); func( "qwer" );

Вывод

(1) (2) (qwer) [qwer] [2] [1]

---

**то есть нужно напечатать  в обычном и обратном порядке ????**

как я понял можно только вызывать одну и ту же функцию... (если да то решение ниже)

1. делаем класс `func` и в нём храним
       std::vector`<std::string>`
2. делаем конструктор func(string) с
       записью дубля в вектор и выводом на
       экран
3. в деструкторе выводим вектор в
       обратном порядке

**UPD::** ну ещё будет "красиво" перегрузить "operator()" дабы не портить конструкторы

Comment: А W[такой вариант][1]W не удовлетворяет условия? За возможную кривизну кода извиняюсь, я не сишник.

  [1]: http://codepad.org/q6BxffMo

Comment: ну на мой личный взгляд нет потому как нарушается 2 условие и будет ошибка при 3

 1. глобальные переменные зло
 2. это тоже изменение массива строки
    (aka буферизация из топика) //нарушает ТЗ
 3. не будет работать правильно при: 

    func("1");
    func("2");
    cout << 100500 <<endl;
    func("qwer");
    cout << s_res <<endl;

**вывод:**  100500 1 2 qwer

**а надо:** 1 2 100500 qwer

Comment: @Bars, IMHO не удовлетворяет основному условию. Может оно и неявное. 

А именно, что в main() кроме вызовов func() **ничего** больше нет.

Без такого условия задача теряет всю свою прелесть.

Comment: 1. Подумал, для задачки это неважно.
2. Удаления символов же нет. А без буферизации тут никак. И у вас есть, просто в массиве.
3. Я, видимо, неверно понял фразу «в программе должна быть 1 единственная функция вывода информации»? Я думал, здесь подразумевается операция вывода в консоль. Кроме того, в условии не сказано, что будет еще какой-то вывод.

Comment: @avp, вот этот вопрос меня в основном и беспокоил

Comment: http://codepad.org/vEMifPPd Вот вам парни. Лютый говнокод конечно но делает что нужно вообще без классов

Comment: @igumnov 

    int main()
    {
        func("1");
        func("2");
        func("qwer");
        func("errors_12345");// а это он выведет?
    }

Comment: Да если каким-то образом отличить последний вызов func от остальных. С ходу могу предложить только решение основанное на метапрограммирование.

Comment: @igumnov: Метапрограммирование? Покажите, интересно.

Comment: @VladD Я имею в виду программу считающую количество вызовов func в исходнике и заменяющую %3  на это количество в определении функции func и запускающуюся перед компиляцией основного кода. Это еще тот костыль но формально он справляется с задачей.

Comment: @igumnov: А! Теперь дошло. Я почему-то подумал про [TMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming).

Comment: @igumnov опять таки только если вывод не зависит от runtime'а...

и если не будет пакостей от препроцессора...

но вообще  буду рад увидеть реализацию с хорошей документацией

Answer (score 7):

[Ещё один вариант](http://ideone.com/Z3fb2N), без глобального списка, но с макросами:

```
#include <iostream>

class StringPrinter
{
    const char* content;
public:
    StringPrinter(const char* s) : content(s)
    {
        std::cout << '(' << content << ')' << std::endl;
    }
    ~StringPrinter()
    {
        std::cout << '[' << content << ']' << std::endl;
    }
};

#define func(S) StringPrinter PASTE1(stringPrinterInstance, __LINE__) (S)
#define PASTE1(T1, T2) PASTE2(T1, T2)
#define PASTE2(T1, T2) T1 ## T2

int main()
{
    func("1");
    func("2");
    func("3");
    func("whatever");
}
```

Comment: Хитро, @VladD, хитро!

Просто здорово придумано генерить имя из номера строки.

Жаль, что вот так, например:

    int main (int ac, char *av[])
    {
      while (ac--)
        func(av[ac]);
    }

не сработает.

Comment: @avp: да, не сработают даже два вызова `func` на одной строке (вот если бы можно было адресовать ещё и номер символа!). Я хотел продемонстрировать неявную вложенность конструкции/деструкции.

Comment: @VladD, это все понятно. Подход нетривиальный, вот что порадовало.

А кстати, Вы уверены, что в любой реализации вызов деструкторов будет в таком вот "стековом" порядке? (Я про это не знал).

Comment: Я думаю, что можно задействовать шаблоны... Но как это сделать красиво!?

Comment: @avp: Да, порядок вызова деструкторов, обратный порядку конструкторов, гарантирован стандартом, я этим всё время пользуюсь с идиомой RAII. Особенно полезно это с блокировками.

Comment: @gecube: да, я тоже ищу решение с template metaprogramming, пока не придумал.

Answer (score 4):

Внесу свои 5 копеек на Си.

Правда не уверен, что формально  этот код отвечает условиям задачи (это я насчет одной функции в программе). По сути же, изображено тоже самое, что ранее показано с классом и его деструктором в С++.

Из main() вызывается только одна функция и никаких "левых" параметров ей не передается.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct list {
  struct list *next;
  char *text;
};
static struct list *list = 0;

static void
rfunc()
{
  struct list *p = list;

  while (p) {
    printf ("[%s]\n",p->text);
    p = p->next;
  }
}

func (char *s)
{
  printf ("(%s)\n",s);
  if (!list)
    atexit(rfunc);
  struct list *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
  p->next = list;
  p->text = s ? strdup(s) : NULL;
  list = p;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  while (ac--)
    func(av[ac]);
}
```

Ничто не упрятано, так сказать, все секреты наружу.

Comment: @avp, раньше не видел примера использования atexit - класс!
Но вот память не освободили...

Comment: О, `atexit` же!

Comment: Мне тоже в голову пришел `atexit`! Думаю, с тем же успехом можно использовать и `setjmp`/`longjmp`

Comment: @avp: Сразу видно, что C -- ваша любовь. (Это комплимент.)

Хотя я бы в `rfunc` сделал `for`.

Comment: @VladD, в принципе, вот так:

      for (typeof(list) p = list; p; p = p->next)
        printf ("[%s]\n",p->text);  // gcc -std=gnu99

мне тоже больше нравится, но набирать -std=gnu99 лень (може вообще на трансляцию g++ переключиться?).


--


@BogolyubskiyAlexey, про память шутки-шутками, но между прочим это (atexit+список/массив) **реально удобная техника** именно для освобождения памяти. 

Только, конечно, не выделенной из кучи (дурацкое занятие при завершении процесса), а тех сегментов shared memory, которые окажутся не нужны после завершения данного процесса.

Comment: @avp: локальные переменные в цикле только с расширениями GNU? Жаль, хорошая фича была бы для обновления стандарта. (Или это для typeof?)

Comment: @VladD, IMHO для typeof().

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно же. Создаем в функции статический объект, который накапливает строки. По завершении работы программы объект разрушается, и в его деструкторе можно вывести строки в нужном порядке:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Collector {
public:
  void push(const std::string& s) {
    data_.push_back(s);
  }

  ~Collector() {
    for (const auto& s: data_) {
      std::cout << "(" << s << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    std::reverse(data_.begin(), data_.end());
    for (const auto& s: data_) {
      std::cout << "[" << s << "]" << std::endl;
    }
  }
private:
  std::vector<std::string> data_;
};

void func(const std::string& s) {
  static Collector collector;
  collector.push(s);
}

int main() {
  func("1");
  func("2");
  func("qwer");
}
```

http://ideone.com/njet2N

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, это фактически решение @ProkletyiPirat, разве нет?

Comment: Кстати, вместо `std::vector` может быть лучше `std::stack`?

Comment: @VladD, да, почти то же самое, но @ProkletyiPirat предлагал использовать объект, а по условию работу должна делать функция.

Comment: Для чистоты идеи можно вообще обойтись без контейнеров

class Collector {
public:
 Collector(): sub = NULL { };
 Collector(std::string &s) { b = s; sub = NULL; };
 ~Collector() { 
  if ( !b.empty() ) std::cout << "(" << b << ")";
  delete sub;
  if ( !b.empty() ) std::cout << "[" << b << "]";
 };

 void push(std::string &s) {
  if ( sub ) sub->push(s);
  else sub = new Collector(s);
 }

 std::string b;
 Collector *sub;
};

Comment: @dzhioev: понял, засчитано :-)

@renegator: переформатируйте, пожалуйста, а? (`картинка_с_котом_из_шрека.jpg`)

Comment: @renegator: о, теперь понял, вы таким образом эмулируете односвязный список, да?

Comment: Да нет, на мой взгляд по семантике это агрегация. А список состоит из равноправных объектов

Comment: @renegator, а что "грязного" в контейнерах? Ваша реализация неочевидна. push работает за O(N). Плюс может не хватить стека, при большом числе элементов.

Comment: И еще электричество может вырубить и предохранители перегореть